# Monogame iOS: How to Add Ordinary UIView?

Tags: ios, monogame

I am trying to figure out how to add UIView to the Monogame. I've done a lot of search over the web and also done a lot experiment but didn't have any luck.

The only way I can think of at this point is to "hack" into the MonoGame.Framework.iOS project and potentially open up some interfaces between iOSGameViewController and actual Game object. But I don't wanna go down this path.

Has anyone done this before? If so, how do you get the reference of the root viewcontroller or root view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain why you are trying to do this? What exactly is your goal here?

Comment: I am trying to integrate Facebook with my game. There are already some pretty good framework out there and I am trying to use it